# iOS 7 app receipt not found after relaunch in sandbox mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store

I am testing app receipt validation logic in sandbox mode and I have a problem with iOS7. On every launch of the app, the app does not have app receipt at appStoreReceiptURL. After I make a purchase or restore purchases, receipt becomes available/present. After I relaunch the app, receipt is missing again. On iOS9 I do not have this kind of problem.
Did anyone have any experience with this kind of problem?
I could ignore the fact that receipt is missing and not verify purchases using the receipt but as I understand (docs), receipt should be available always (after it is available for the first time, sometimes you can refresh it if there is not receipt available).

Hope you understand the problem and someone had this problem and found the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

In test environment the first request always return nil, because no actual purchase is made.
This is different from production where an app (each kind of app) has its own receipt (this is valid from >= iOS7).
I'm not able to tell you why after restart the receipt is still nil, but on the Apple dev forum there are a lot of answers about "weird" behavior in sandbox.

Comment: Tnx! I hope it will work as explained in the docs. There are always "weird" stuff in sandbox :D please Apple make sandbox better :D It would be great if someone had similar usecase and it worked ok for them in production environment.